# Confidence Interval's in a nested function

Tags: r, function, functional-programming, aggregate-functions, confidence-interval

New student in R, taking a very accelerated class with little/no instruction.  Please be patient with me...so far y'all have been extremely helpful, and I appreciate it.  I apologize in advance if this doesn't make sense.

I am trying to make a function that reads columns from an object with columns "year", "complex", "mean", "2_sd", and "n" and calculates the confidence interval, then merges the lower and upper CI's as two separate columns into a new object with the same dimensions as the products of the CI calculations.  However, I keep getting an error:

code for lower CI:

```
x=aggregate(m.all$mean, by=list(year,complex),FUN=(m.all$mean - qnorm(0.9) * sd(m.all$mean)/sqrt(m.all$n)))
```

error:

```
'(m.all$mean - qnorm(0.9) * sd(m.all$mean)/sqrt(m.all$n))' is not a function, character or symbol
```

I tried to use:

```
x=aggregate(total_male, by=list(year,complex),FUN=t.test(total_male,conf.level=0.90))
```

(where "total_male", "year", "complex" variables were sourced from the BASE object) but R doesn't recognize t.test when it's inside aggregate() for some reason...

The BASE object is 3 columns of "year", "complex", "total_males".  The NEW object has "year", "complex", "mean", "2_sd", and "n"

I built "mean", 2_sd" and "n" out of the BASE object, with functions, and then merged them to create the NEW object, so I understand that.  But CI's is confusing me.

The BASE object has been attach()'ed so I could work with the variables more easily.

Any ideas?
NEW object:

`m.all
  year     complex     mean X2st.dev  n
1 2007    3corners 26.28571 52.04760  7
2 2007        Blue 18.87500 20.15476  8
3 2007 book_cliffs  4.50000 13.19091  6
4 2007     Diamond 13.25000 48.83431 20`

The OLD object is 41 observations (all in 2007) of 4 complexes, with various numeric tot_male values:
`head(d4)
    year  complex tot_male
2   2007  Diamond       17
21  2007 3corners       19
36  2007     Blue       40
73  2007  Diamond       22
85  2007  Diamond        0
115 2007  Diamond        2`

Comment: Post output of dput(m.all) or, if it is too large, head(m.all) here for everyone to understand clearly the data.

Comment: @rnso sorry, how's that?

Comment: @ Charlie: your feedback will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following may be what you want (since mean and sd have already been generated):

```
> m.all$lowerci = with(m.all, mean - qnorm(0.9)*X2st.dev/sqrt(n))
> m.all
   year     complex     mean X2st.dev  n    lowerci
1: 2007    3corners 26.28571 52.04760  7  1.0748434
2: 2007        Blue 18.87500 20.15476  8  9.7429407
3: 2007 book_cliffs  4.50000 13.19091  6 -2.4013685
4: 2007     Diamond 13.25000 48.83431 20 -0.7441377
```

Similarly for upper CI:

```
> m.all$upperci = with(m.all, mean + qnorm(0.9)*X2st.dev/sqrt(n))
> m.all
   year     complex     mean X2st.dev  n    lowerci  upperci
1: 2007    3corners 26.28571 52.04760  7  1.0748434 51.49658
2: 2007        Blue 18.87500 20.15476  8  9.7429407 28.00706
3: 2007 book_cliffs  4.50000 13.19091  6 -2.4013685 11.40137
4: 2007     Diamond 13.25000 48.83431 20 -0.7441377 27.24414
```

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, but since X2st.dev is 2 standard deviations, I need to divide it by 2 in order to calculate the true lower CI.  Can I just put X2st.dev/2 in parenthesis, or do I have to do that outside of the `with()` statement?  When I do that, I get 13.68 for the lowerCI, but my "professor" has -363.5.
@rnso

Comment: Also, is there a way to put it in a command similar to this: `> d2.n=aggregate(tot_male,by=list(year,complex),FUN=length)
> names(d2.n)[1:3]=c("year","complex","n")
> m.all=merge(m.all,d2.n,by=c(1:2))
> m.all'
That is how I originally built m.all

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how to construct an R function. All you have now is an expression but it's not capable of accepting arguments. Perhaps:

```
 x=aggregate(m.all$mean, by=list(year,complex),
            FUN=function(v){ v - qnorm(0.9) * sd(v)/sqrt(length(v)) })
```

Please do not `attach` data objects. It just ends up making things less stable and less easy to understand. If 'm.all' is actually a dataframe with named columns "mean", "year", then the first line you proposed might be:

```
 with( m.all, aggregate(mean, by=list(year,complex),
            FUN=function(v){ v - qnorm(0.9) * sd(v)/sqrt(length(v)) }))
```

With lets you create a small environment where the column names will get interpreted as objects. Generally it's is a bad idea to use names like `mean` and `sd` since those are functions names.

Comment: `> with(m.all,aggregate(mean, by=list(year,complex), FUN=function(v){v-qnorm(0.9)*sd(v)/sqrt(length(v))}))`

@BondedDust when I run it, I get a column of years, and complexes, but the third column is all NA's.  I `detached` everything before running it.  Also, I want to add two columns to "m.all", one being lowerCI, and one being upperCI.  Will I be able to do that after running your code?  Note I added the NEW object to my original post.  That's the data I'd like to work with, and add the columns to.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't really try to set you up to get two columns of confidence intervals because you didn't offer any data initially. Was just trying to help out with teh mechanics of `aggregate`. Looks like @mso has handled it.